# Getting error Cannot find module 'app/dashboard/first/first.module'

Tags: angular

I am getting a weird error. I am developing angular 4 based project. 
Following in my code structure

- app
- app.component.html
- app.component.ts
- app.module.ts
- app.routing.module.ts

  - dashboard
  - dashboard.component.html
  - dashboard.component.ts
  - dashboard.module.ts
  - dashboard.routing.module.ts

    - first
    - first.component.html
    - first.component.ts
    - first.module.ts
    - first.routing.module.ts

When I try to load first from dashboard, I get following error.

```
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module 'app/dashboard/first/first.module'.
Error: Cannot find module 'app/dashboard/first/first.module'.
    at webpackAsyncContext (src async:14)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadAndCompile (core.es5.js:5644)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load (core.es5.js:5632)
    at RouterConfigLoader.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (router.es5.js:3417)
    at RouterConfigLoader.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.RouterConfigLoader.load (router.es5.js:3401)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (router.es5.js:1569)
```

Following is my app.routing.module code

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
     { path: '', loadChildren: 'app/login/login.module' },
    { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module' },

];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

At compile time there is no error. However when I add a space in dashboard.routing.module.ts and save the file, the error goes away and the routing works perfectly. It runs smoothly till I restart node server.

Comment: show the code app.routing.module.ts file , how your are setting lazy load paths?

Comment: I have edited my question and added app.routing.module code.

Comment: where is the first module loadchildren path in the app.routing.module.ts file?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833580/how-to-give-correct-path-names-for-loadchildren-in-lazy-loading-angular-2-ngmodu

Comment: Thanks Sathish. The link helped me to solve the problem. I revisited all the modules and removed default from 'export default class AppRoutingModule { }'. I had some other modules which was having default was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the code like this.

```
   const routes: Routes = [
                    { path: '', loadChildren: 'app/login/login.module#loginModule'},
                    { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#dashboardModule' },     
                    { path: 'dashboard/first',loadChildren:'app/dashboard/first.module#firstModule'}
                 ];
               @NgModule({
                    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
                    exports: [RouterModule]
           })
        export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

see more on loadChildren info [Loadchildren concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110827/angular2-router-how-to-correctly-load-children-modules-with-their-own-routing-r)